# Heroku deploy node.js application with google drive

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-drive-api

I'm experiencing a problem with deploying my application which using google drive in Heroku.
The first time login for google drive API requires a code and paste it to command-line when running it, unfortunately, the Heroku does not provide a bash so I can do that, is there anything I`m missing from the documentation, or is just unavailable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Instead of describing your code to us (this isn't very clear), _show it to us_. If you have too much code to include, make a [mcve].

Comment: Specifically, why do think you need to provide your users with a terminal? That would be _very_ unusual for a web application.

Comment: The Heroku documentations for deploying apps are quite good and I've never had too much trouble with deployment. I would search for a Youtube tutorial on it to get your feet wet if this is your first time though.

Comment: Do you have a git repo so we can take a closer look?

Answer (score -1):

I find this solution useful to me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766913/14351872
about how to skip the enter code step for google drive